# Percona Xtradb Cluster not accepting options on command line

Tags: mysql, replication, clustering, percona, galera

I am using Percona Xtradb Cluster 5.6 and trying to start my cluster through a donor node via command line and I am getting this error:

CentOS 7:

> systemctl start mysql --wsrep-sst-donor=srv1
>
> systemctl: unrecognized option '--wsrep-sst-donor=srv1'

I am running 3 nodes cluster. I have started my first node-A with bootstrap, then started second node-B which synced with node-A and now i want my third node-C to sync with the first one node-A as well, but unfortunately it was getting sync with node-B.
how can i pass an option for donor on command line in centos7?

Comment: You can't give command line arguments in systemctl to systemd initscripts. You need to edit the corresponding service file in /etc/systemd/system or in /lib/systemd/system (second is dirty, create a copy in /etc/systemd/system instead). If you give an argument, it would be interpreted as a systemctl argument, this is why you've got the error message.